# How gets the Authorization Header injected into the WebServiceContext

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, websphere

In an application I am using the WebServiceContext, which gets injected by the application server.

```
@Resource
private WebServiceContext context;
```

From this context I am reading the username and password for authentication (Note: I am not doing authentication by the application server, the application itself authenticate users per request).

In the Http-Request I am sending the Authorization Header f.e.:

> Basic MTAzfdajfljakdfjkla=

So the question is, does the container reads the Autorization Header, then converts the value of the Header using a Base64 decoder and writes it to the WebServiceContext Object, because there are the password and username decrypted?

My actual problem is:
I would like to read the username and password from the HTTP-Header in a RESTFul Web Service to authenticate the user by the application per request. 
Is there an easy way to get these two decoded values from the HTTP Header, maybe using injection? If yes, how?
Otherwise I will convert the Authorization Header by myself to plain text using Base64 encoder...!

Comment: What have you tried, and what are you trying to obtain from WebServiceContext? I don't see from it how you could obtain anything other than the actual Request headers.

Comment: @dbreaux: From the WebServiceContext I am trying to obtain the decoded password and username of the user, who is sending the request. Unfortunately, when I am using REST the WebServiceContext doesnt get injected, so I cant obtain the username/password. Therefore I am injecting the HttpHeader and read the Authorization Header. Using this method, I have to decode the Authorization Header using a Base64 decoder. My question is, if there is a more convenient method to do this...